# Make a small script to sort the vectors in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: javascript, adobe-illustrator

Make a script to sort the vectors in Illustrator. In the cycle you want the first layer to sort of the vector is less than a certain value, copy to new layer, delete the old one. On the next cycle again on the first layer to do the same, but less than the other values. In the end, each layer needs to sort the layers by size. My code is not working correctly.

```
enter code here



var k =0;
for(j=0; j<10; j++) {
var mySelection = activeDocument.layers[0].pageItems;
var newlayer4 = activeDocument.layers.add(); 
   k=k+ 10000;
   for (i=0; i<(mySelection.length); i++){
    obj_gabarit=Math.abs(mySelection[i].area);
    if(obj_gabarit<k){
     mySelection[i].duplicate(newlayer4);
     mySelection[i].remove();
    }
   }

 }
```

code here